# How to push into GitHub if I didn't work on a project for a few days?

Tags: git

I haven't worked on my project for 5 days and now I can not push my new work.

What I did:

1. Create a new file in my project
2. `git add --all`
3. `git commit -m "my text message"`

I get `HEAD detached at origin/master Changes not staged for commit no changes added to commit` Error. But I **just** created a new file and it's still there.

What happened there? Nobody except me works on this repository. I didn't touch it for 5 days straight. It used to work just fine, but now I can not store my work on GitHub for somereason?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/how-do-i-fix-a-git-detached-head

Answer (score 1):

It seems you currently are not on a (non-detached) branch. Switch to an existing branch and commit your changes then.